# How to Read the orientation change from another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, screen-orientation

I made a menu button that users can change the orientation in landscape or portrait. my first activity doing well with the rotation, But when I go to my second activity the activity's rotation change and the app crash.

This is my first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;
int Number = 0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("@##,###,###,###");

/** SharedPreferences */
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
int currentOrientation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** Rotation SharedPreferences */
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int orienation = preferences.getInt("orientation", -1);
    if (orienation != -1) {
        setRequestedOrientation(orienation);
    }
    /** End */

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState == null) {
        outState = new Bundle();
    }
    outState.putInt("currentOrientation",
            Integer.valueOf(currentOrientation));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    currentOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentOrientation");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        /** Rotation */
    case R.id.menuRotate:
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            editor.putInt("orientation",
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            editor.putInt("orientation",
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        editor.commit();

        break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

As long as I am in my first activity everything is good. but when I go to the second Activity the orientation change automatically and the app crashing givin me this error:

E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.com.test/com.com.test.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class

**My question is** that how can I read the sharedpreferences in my SecondActivity from my First activity?

I tried to use this code in my SecondActivity:

```
private Context context; 

public void onCreate(){ 
 super.onCreate();
 context = getApplicationContext();
```

But nothing happen so far. The app crash when I go to SecondActivity cause of oreintation change.

Here is my **SecondActivity**:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I didn't get what do you want to do, but the crash is in R.layout.second_activity.

Comment: Well, according to InflateException you probably used values that are only in values-land or values-port or some class that is misspelled in the layout. Try if second_activity works by itself in first place.

Comment: lets say my first activity is in portrait and my phone is in landscape when i go to the second_activity the app change the orientation automatically cause I haven't save the orientation in my second_activity and its automatically get the orientation from the sensor and the app crash. I just want to get the saved orientation from my first activity and use it to my second_activity.

Comment: the second activity works fine when the first_activity and the phone is in the same orientation, then when I go to the second_activity nothing is happening and it working normally.

Comment: I don't thing the first activity matters. If you open the second activity and change orientation it will crash. That's all about it. Search for problems in xml.

Comment: No, there is no problem with xml. Cause when I take the sharedprefereces away from my first activity and let the sensor decide the orientation the app working perfectly ... but I need that users can chose in which orientation they want to use the app.

Comment: some layout you're inflating by setContentView() or manually based on SharedPreferences state refuses to inflate.